# Facing an issue in setup docker distribution library using glide

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, openshift, glide-golang

I have been trying to set up the `github.com/docker/distribution/` library in my local machine using the `glide up -v`. I have other dependent libraries kubernetes, openshift with docker. Installing setup if failing.

## I was getting the following errors:

```
[INFO]  Project relies on 54 dependencies.
[INFO]  Removing nested vendor and Godeps/_workspace directories...
[INFO]  Removing: /vendor/github.com/docker/distribution/vendor
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x30 pc=0x6fdc82]

goroutine 1 [running]: github.com/Masterminds/glide/path.StripVendor.func1(0xc42054a420, 0x60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x8f3160, 0xc4202d70e0, 0x0, 0x0)
/home/vagrant/go/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/path/strip.go:28 +0x42 path/filepath.walk(0xc4205e8900, 0x55, 0x8fa0e0, 0xc420555520, 0xc4203be880, 0x0, 0x0)
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/path/filepath/path.go:377 +0x20d path/filepath.walk(0xc4204f8f50, 0x4e, 0x8fa0e0, 0xc4201c41a0, 0xc4203be880, 0x0, 0x0)
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/path/filepath/path.go:381 +0x2c2 path/filepath.walk(0xc4204f8e60, 0x41, 0x8fa0e0, 0xc4201c40d0, 0xc4203be880, 0x0, 0x0)
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/path/filepath/path.go:381 +0x2c2 path/filepath.walk(0xc420342580, 0x3a, 0x8fa0e0, 0xc4205dc5b0, 0xc4203be880, 0x0, 0x0)
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/path/filepath/path.go:381 +0x2c2 path/filepath.walk(0xc4203edf50, 0x2f, 0x8fa0e0, 0xc4205dc410, 0xc4203be880, 0x0, 0x20)
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/path/filepath/path.go:381 +0x2c2 path/filepath.Walk(0xc4203edf50, 0x2f, 0xc4203be880, 0xc4205dc340, 0x0)
/usr/lib/go-1.10/src/path/filepath/path.go:403 +0x106 
github.com/Masterminds/glide/path.StripVendor(0x8b0354, 0x3b)
/home/vagrant/go/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/path/strip.go:22 +0x10a
github.com/Masterminds/glide/action.Update(0xc4201b4680, 0x890100)
/home/vagrant/go/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/action/update.go:108 +0x291 main.commands.func13(0xc4200d6f20, 0x0, 0xc4200d6f20)
/home/vagrant/go/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/glide.go:634 +0x354
github.com/Masterminds/glide/vendor/github.com/codegangsta
/cli.HandleAction(0x811280, 0x8ba958, 0xc4200d6f20, 0xc42006d200, 0x0)
/home/vagrant/go/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/vendor/github.com/codegangsta/cli/app.go:490 +0xc8
 github.com/Masterminds/glide/vendor/github.com/codegangsta/cli.Command.Run(0x8999f4, 0x6, 0x898661, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x8a5188, 0x1f, 0x0, ...)
/home/vagrant/go/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/vendor/github.com/codegangsta/cli/command.go:210 +0xa36
github.com/Masterminds/glide/vendor/github.com/codegangsta/cli.(*App).Run(0xc42008b1e0, 0xc42001e090, 0x3, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0)
/home/vagrant/go/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/vendor/github.com/codegangsta/cli/app.go:255 +0x6a0 main.main()
/home/vagrant/go/src/github.com/Masterminds/glide/glide.go:104 +0x5a9
```

Comment: It really looks like a `glide` bug. What glide version are you using?

Comment: I was using the glide version 0.13.1-3

Comment: The issue is fixed by updating the go to 1.11 and glide to 13.2 versions.